# Creating a sound recording pipeline in windows 7 to add effects

Tags: windows-7, audio, audio-recording, vst

Say I have some program which takes input from an audio recording device; for example a VOIP dialer.
Now I wish to apply a sound effect from a VST plugin to the input device. It seems to me that a sensible way to do this would be to have some VST audio program take input from the mic device, apply the sound effect, write the output to a virtual audio device and have the end program read from the virtual device.

If this seems like a logical way to go about the problem, how do I go about creating virtual audio devices in Windows 7, and what VST program would allow me to read live input audio, apply an effect, and write it to the virtual device? For the latter, I assume there would be many programs capable of this, but I would appreciate a recommendation.

Comment: Why don't you just record the input first and apply an effect afterwards?

Comment: I want a live effect. For example making a VOIP phone call will require a live data stream.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these two:

- [VST Host](http://www.hermannseib.com/english/vsthost.htm) which acts as realtime VST processing unit. It allows you to chain any VST plugins between input and output.
- [VB-Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/) which is literary virtual input/output device. It allows you to use output from any program as input in another.

To join these tools set the VST Host wave-output to 'Cable input' (so the processed sound will go to virtual cable) and also you need your to change your or your VOIP software sound input to 'Cable output' (because it is output from your virtual cable)